# How to align these Semantic UI dropdown borders?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm using the Semantic UI dropdown and I'm trying to increase the border-width.

This is my problem:

[image]
The dropdown's border and menu's border are not aligned. How can I fix it?

You can reproduce my problem on this page: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Just add a `border-width: 2px` to the div with `ui dropdown selection active visible` classes, then the same property to the children div with `menu transition visible` classes.

Menu has a different size of the dropdown, so I tried to apply a `width: calc(100% + 2px);` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some additional css properties which need to be amended:

```
.ui.selection.dropdown .menu {
  margin: 0 -2px; // same amount as border width
  min-width: calc(100% + 4px); // left + right border width
  width: calc(100% + 4px); // left + right border width
}
```

Once you do that, the dropdown looks fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just before your answer I tried another solution, with `left: -1px; width: 101%;` but it wasn't totally responsive. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)